# A summand of a GCS module is a GCS module

Tags: modules

Recall that a right $R$-module $M$ is *CS* if for every submodule $N\subseteq M$ there exists a summand $L \subseteq^{\oplus} M$ such that $N$ is an essential submodule of $L$.

It's well-known that a summand of a CS module is again CS (see, for instance, *Continuous and Discrete modules* by Mohamed and Müller, Proposition 2.7, page 20).

The class of CS modules was generalized as follows: A right $R$-module $M$ is called *GCS (generalized $CS$-module)* if for every submodules $A, B \subseteq M$ with $A \cong B$ and $A \cap B = 0$ there exists $K, L \subseteq^{\oplus} M$ such that $A$ is essential in $K$ and $B$ is essential in $L$.

I ask whether a summand of a GCS module is again GCS.

**Another question on GCS-modules:** Is the following statement true?

If $M$ is GCS and $f \colon M \to M'$ is any homomorphism with $M'$ nonsingular, then $\ker f \subseteq^{\oplus} M$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See *Continuous and Discrete modules* by Mohamed and Muller, Proposition 2.7, p. 20